# Есть ли что-то удобнее чем списки и словари в python для работы со сложными связями и большой вложенностью данных?

Tags: python, pandas, структуры-данных

Я работаю с координатами для разных точек, группы точек могут быть соединены линиями и представлять разные фигуры. Между собой фигуры тоже могут иметь разные связи о объединяться бОльшие объекты и т. д.

Для манипулирования всеми этими данными используются списки и словари. Но вложенность и структура получается довольно большая и запутанная. Есть ли что-то удобнее?

Может pandas например или еще что-то посоветуйте пжл

Comment: Ну, соответствующие классы для каждой сущности, наверное?

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону Geopandas или библиотеки shapely, которую он использует. А тот в свою очередь, как и сам Pandas, использует более общую numpy.

Comment: Не используйте базовые классы в чистом виде, используйте классы, специально написанные под ваши данные, и тогда не будет никакой путаницы, если хорошо классы написать